# Sqlite query for fetching latest Exam date time with distinct patientID

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

In Sqlite db I have a table: Examination with columns ExamID, InternalPID, ExamDateTime

```
ExamID InternalPID ExamDateTime (from left to right) 
1 2 2015-03-11
2 1 2015-11-11 
3 4 2015-05-01 
4 6 2015-08-10 
5 2 2015-04-22 
6 1 2014-12-11 
7 2 2015-03-12
```

the query output should be latest Examination date of each patient. i.e the InternalPID should be distinct with its latest ExamDateTime.

Expect output from query:

```
ExamID InternalPID ExamDateTime
5 2 2015-04-22
2 1 2015-11-11
3 4 2015-05-01
4 6 2015-08-10
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a join and aggregation or a clever `where` clause:

```
select e.*
from examination e
where e.ExamDateTime = (select max(e2.ExamDateTime)
                        from examination e2
                        where e2.patientid = e.patientid
                       );
```

Comment: @1218GG :    Then, please help the answerer by marking his answer as 'Accepted'.

Comment: Sorry but StackOverflow says I need to earn reputation of 15 in order to mark this answer as accepted. And this was my first question ever on stack overflow